# Should I make a class static?

Tags: java, oop

I've got the following class:

```
class A
{
    private String state;

    A() { state = staticGetterCall(); } // staticGetterCall is fast

    bool shouldUseState() { return state != null; }

    bool getState() { return state; }
}
```

And then I use that `class A` in the following way in some other constructor:

```
B(...) {
    ...
    A a = new A();
    if (a.shouldUseState())
    {
        staticFunction2Call(a.getState());
    }
}
```

That's the only place I use `A`, so I think it's a good idea to refactor this and make these 2 method static (and inline that `String state`):

```
class A
{
    bool shouldUseState() { return staticGetterCall != null; }

    bool getState() { return staticGetterCall; } 
}
```

So its usage transforms to:

```
B(...) {
    ...
    if (A.shouldUseState())
    {
        staticFunction2Call(A.getState());
    }
}
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Are you making things static for optimization purposes?

Comment: No need to create `static` method inside `classA` to access them.
by-default all methods are public inside static class.
one more loophole is that if you make them static methods then you can't use non-static variables inside it!

Comment: @Radhey what are you talking about?

Comment: @Kayaman I don't really like the way I use A a = new A() and then 2 method calls inside of B's class constructor.

Comment: @Kayaman , he is trying to make that 2 methods static, at the other end he is also creating object of that class.

Comment: I saw people burning thousands of € on refactoring static things into non-static things. I'm yet to see someone who would really need to refactor non-static things into static things.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I make a class static?

To answer your question, you need to know the good and bad points of this usage.

According to [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch), [Effective Java 2Edition](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_17?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=effective%20java%202nd%20edition&sprefix=effective%20java%202n%2Cstripbooks%2C443&crid=2SYUBIG27P6CJ), **Item 1**, let me list his point of view of advantages and disadvantages of static usage over constructors. So you can decide for your program effectively.

**Advantages:**
1. One advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they have names.
2. A second advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they are not required to create a new object each time they’re invoked.
3. A third advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they can return an object of any subtype of their return type.
4. A fourth advantage of static factory methods is that they reduce the verbosity of creating parameterized type instances.

**Disadvantages**
1. The main disadvantage of providing only static factory methods is that classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed.
2. A second disadvantage of static factory methods is that they are not readily distinguishable from other static methods.

In short, static factory methods and public constructors both have their uses, and it pays to understand their relative merits.
Often static factories are preferable, so avoid the reflex to provide public constructors without first considering static factories.

Answer (score 0):

> That's the only place I use A, so I think it's a good idea to refactor
>   this and make these 2 method static (and inline that String state):

It is not a reason to make an instance method static.
`static` members (methods or fields) are not specific to an instance of the class but are associated to the class itself.
If you define these methods as `static`, you will have to do some other changes : the `state` field should also be `static` and the constructor would also have no sense any longer as static method doesn't access to instance members.

So is it make really sense to make the whole class state and behavior as `static` ?
If the state depends on the `A` instance created, keep them as instance members.
And besides in a general way as you have a state in a class, make all `static` seems to be counter intuitive.
At last, `static` modifiers don't ease the switches to other implementations  (and consequently also mocking in unit test). So, you should also consider this point before to make them `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Following code makes sense to me

```
class A {

    private static Boolean state;

    A() {
        state = staticGetterCall();
    } // staticGetterCall is fast

    private boolean staticGetterCall() {
        return true;
    }

    static boolean shouldUseState() {
        return state != null;
    }

    static boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }
}

class B {
    B() {
        A a = new A();
        if (A.shouldUseState()) {
            staticFunction2Call(a.getState());
        }
    }

    private void staticFunction2Call(boolean state) {
    }
}
```

There were few changes required in your code. These are trivial and I think you are aware of these.
1. Declare state field as static 
2. Change datatype of state to Boolean. Right now it is declared as String.